# Do I need to restore dealloc in xcode4.2?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, dealloc

I'm new to application development on the iPhone. According to the tutorial, there should be a `dealloc` function in `ViewController.m`. However it's disappeared. Is there something else I should use to release the memory?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by "disappeared", you mean that a project created from Apple's templates didn't include it, then that's because you selected Automatic Reference Counting when creating the project (the default setting in 4.2).  You can [read about it in Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html), but basically the compiler now keeps track of objects for you, so no need to release them.

Comment: I use 'retain' in the @property of the label object, and there's a [labelobject release] in the dealloc in the tutorial. So I no need do it?

Comment: If you're using automatic reference counting, then no. The `release` call will happen automatically.

Comment: But you'll need to use "strong" instead of "retain".  ARC is new in 5.0.  It's great, but there are differences, and older tutorials won't know about it. See Apple's release note (referenced in my answer above now).